# Adding string variable to xpath c# selenium

Tags: c#, string, selenium, xpath, partial

I have probably spent a good 8 hours trying to figure this out but am constantly failing. I have searched an age for a solution

I am trying to find an selenium element by partial id match using xpath (c# selenium libraries). The following works perfectly fine. The partial text is sel_1-rowse1

```
IWebElement elem = wait5.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@id,'sel_1-rowsel')]")));
```

However when I want to use a variable named partial this does not work

```
string partial = "sel_1-rowse1";
IWebElement search = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//a[contains(@id,'{0}')]", partial))));
```

or

```
IWebElement search = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//a[contains(@id,{0})]", partial))));
```

I have tried single quotes double quotes and escape chars. But cant figure this out. I cant even provide the error as its picking up a valid id. Brain is severely depleted on this one.

Comment: "does not work?" How? What's the output from your two examples above?

Comment: Sorry my debugging was fairly difficult as I could not debug on the network  I ran the program on, Constant use of Console.Writeline to see what was happening in the program. The next two replies resoved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an observation, the first example element id ends with lower case 'L' (so l) while the second one with number 1. Might be just a copy paste error but worth asking...

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem. It took this long to not notice the difference between     1 and l . Always stuns me how many hours I can spend on something so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

[`partial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd.aspx) is a reserved keyword in C#.

Refactor `partial` to something else (not reserved by C#) and you should be golden.

Comment: Brilliant. This did not resolve the issue alone but I did remove partial